# SWIFT Show filtered JSON Array on Table View Controller

Tags: json, swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I'm a beginner and currently work on this self-practicing project. I'm trying to get data from JSON and filter data by country (below I'm filtering for Italy data only). Then I want to save this filtered array to *dataArray* and show it on Table View but it doesn't work. Please let me know what I'm missing. Thanks!

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!

    struct Spot : Decodable {
        let Province: String
        let Country : String
        let Last_Update : String
        let Confirmed : String
        let Deaths : String
        let Recovered : String
        let Latitude : String?
        let Longitude : String?

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case Province = "Province/State"
            case Country = "Country/Region"
            case Last_Update = "Last Update"
            case Confirmed
            case Deaths
            case Recovered
            case Latitude
            case Longitude
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var TableView: UITableView!

    //Constants

    let covid_URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zmsp/coronavirus-json-api/master/latest.json"
    var dataArray : [[String : Any]] = []
    let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.TableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
        TableView.delegate = self
        TableView.dataSource = self

        getData()

        TableView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func getButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {



    }


    //MARK: - Networking

    //getData method:
    func getData () {

        let url = URL(string: covid_URL)!

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()

            do {
                let rates = try decoder.decode([Spot].self, from: data)
                let rate = rates.filter { $0.Country == "Italy"}
                let dataArray = rate

                self.TableView.reloadData()
            }

            catch {
                print("Error after loading",error)
            }
        }.resume()

    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> NSInteger {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: NSInteger) -> NSInteger {
        return dataArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var dict = dataArray[indexPath.row] as! [String : String]
        let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        let confirmed = dict["Confirmed"]
        cell.textLabel!.text = confirmed

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check the dataArray after API call? Is it empty or have data?

Comment: yes, it has data. I've tried printing the json after calling and the call was successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove let keyword from dataArray inside API call where you assign your filter data. That is,

```
do {
    let rates = try decoder.decode([Spot].self, from: data)
    let rate = rates.filter { $0.Country == "Italy"}
    dataArray = rate
    self.TableView.reloadData()
} catch {
    print("Error after loading",error)
}
```

**set dataArray of type your Spot class instead of dictionary array.**

like this:-

```
var dataArray = [Spot]()
```

Comment: I was able to fixed it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
let rate = rates.filter { $0.Country == "Italy"}
self.dataArray = rate // Instead of creating new object, assign to previously declared

self.TableView.reloadData()
```

Also, Update this

```
var dataArray : [Spot] = []
```

Comment: I fixed it successfully. Thanks for the help!